# How to correctly join data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Position**:

[image]

**Contract**:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to have one table with details attached from contract table to position table

However when I do

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    dbo.Position p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Contract c ON (p.ID = c.ID)
```

I get

[image]

which I do not understand, why there are 4 records for id=4? Am I missing something? As in subject, I'm working with SQL Server.

**EDIT**: maybe I will post a full problem I am trying to solve, maybe above step is not necessary. What I want to achieve is to identify records where, first `fdate_from` from position does not match first `date_from` from contract (color black). The second part of the problem is to identify all records where last `date_to` from position column does not match last `date_to` from contract.

Query to produce below table I used was:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.Position c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Contract p ON (p.ID = c.ID)
ORDER BY 
    p.id, p.date_from, p.date_to, c.date_from, c.date_to ASC
```

[image]

**EDIT2**: Part 1 of the problems seems to be solved:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT  
         p.id,
         MIN(p.date_from) AS p_date_from,
         MIN(c.date_from) AS c_date_from
     FROM 
         dbo.Position p
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Contract c ON (p.ID = c.ID)
     GROUP BY 
         p.id) AS m
WHERE 
    m.p_date_from != m.c_date_from
ORDER BY 
    id
```

yet part 2 seems to be more complex ... as there are nulls which will probably be ignored by max

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT  
         p.id,
         MAX(p.date_to) AS p_date_to,
         MAX(c.date_to) AS c_date_to
     FROM
         dbo.Position p
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Contract c ON (p.ID = c.ID)
     GROUP BY 
         p.id) AS m
WHERE
    m.p_date_to != m.c_date_to
ORDER BY 
    id
```

**EDIT 3**: finally, the second condition with support from http://www.bradleyschacht.com/select-null-as-max-or-min-in-sql-query/

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT  
         p.id,
         MAX(COALESCE(p.date_to, '2099-12-31')) AS p_date_to,
         MAX(COALESCE(c.date_to, '2099-12-31')) AS c_date_to
     FROM
         dbo.Position p
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Contract c ON (p.ID = c.ID)
     GROUP BY 
         p.id) AS m
WHERE
    m.p_date_to != m.c_date_to
ORDER BY 
    id
```

I'll leave it here for the future

Comment: It pairs two positions with Id 4 with 2 contracts with ID 4, that results in four. If you want to pair only with matching date you have to add that to the join condition. (Which does make the data model rather strangebut you did not give details on the semantics)

Comment: what is the result that you want ?

Comment: 2 x 2 = 4    Question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you, use HAVING condition for this type of quay. it will grate help for your development. Thank You!

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

[SQL HAVING Clause - W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)